# Define the type of an object with string keys and function values

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics, functional-programming

I have a node JS function with one parameter that is an object with keys and the values are functions that then resolve to the underlying values.

We have just switched over to TS and I don't know how to define the key:value types of a parameter and further I don't know how to define a `function` as the value type?

The TS function looks like this...

```
const myJSFunction = o => input => ...
```

Where `o` is the `string:function` object. And `input` is then passed into each of the function `values` of `o`.

So I was thinking of having some signature along the lines of...

```
// define the generic <R> function as <U => any>
// define the generic <T> as an object of { string : R }
const myTSFunction = (o: T) => (input: U) => ...
```

Or something? I'm clutching at straws here as I don't know Typescript well enough to know what is possible with generics.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grégory NEUT answer helped a lot but there were some other constraints that I discovered on the way (that JS had been hiding away). I'm using Lodash so my object was not just an object but a type that they had defined.

So I defined some new types...

```
type TransformerFunction<T> = (o: T) => any;
type TransformerObject<T> = Dictionary<TransformerFunction<T>>;
```

And then the function became like...

```
export const objectTransform = <T extends any>(o: TransformerObject<T>) => <U extends T>(json: U): Dictionary<any> => _.flow(
  _.mapValues((f: TransformerFunction<T>) => f(json)),
  _.omitBy(_.isUndefined),
  _.omit('undefined'),
)(o);
```

This is how I have been transforming JSON in JS and now moving it over to TS and loving the generics.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this :

```
// We define what the type o is
// key: string means "any key should ..."
interface Obj<T> {
  [key: string]: (input: T) => void,
};

// We instantiate an object for the test
const o: Obj<string> = {
  a: (input) => { },
  b: (input) => { },
};

// We define the function to work with any type of value of obj
// and call it for the test
function myTSFunction<T>(obj: Obj<T>, val: T): void {
  obj[0](val);
}
```

Comment: Ooh... this looks promising. I'll give it a go, thanks.

Comment: In the end I found a slightly different way of doing it but this helped a lot. Thanks! I've up voted and I'll post the solution I got in the end.